# C# Data Table holds value to 2dp, but looses 2dp when transferred to a Data Row

Tags: c#

I place the results of a stored procedure call into a Data Table.  The stored procedure returns one column as decimal and returns for example 500.00, 500.20.

When this is placed into my data table, I inspect the contents and can see that the decimal places are retained.

However when I loop round the data table to read each of the rows in a for each loop `e.g. for each (DataRow row in datatablename.Rows),` if I then inspect the contents of  row i have 500 and 500.20 i.e. it looses the zeros after the decimal place.

I need to be able to retain the zeros after the decimal place for display purposes.

The data table that I have used is a generic data table `e.g. DataTable results = new DataTable().`

The table needs to be generic, rather than explicitly declaring each column as the results of many different stored procedures need to go into this table and each stored procedure returns different results (i.e. i don't want to declare some 20 specific data tables).

Any ideas on how I get the DataRow to retain the zeros after the decimal place?

Answer (score 1):

You should format the value last of all where you want to show it(f.e. in your loop):

```
string value = doubleVal.ToString("N2")
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k.aspx